# Turning a method into an enumerable method

Tags: ruby, oop, instance-methods

I rewrote the `map` method:

```
def my_map(input, &block)
  mod_input = []
  x = -1
  while x < input.length - 1
    x = x + 1
    if block == nil
      return input
      break
    end
    mod_input.push(block.call(input[x]))
  end
  return mod_input
end
```

I need to call this code as I would call `map` or `reverse`. Does anyone know the syntax for that?

Comment: Have you written this method within the `Array` class?

Comment: You can call it like `my_map [1,2,3] {|x| x + 1}` - is that not something you want?

Comment: There are methods [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), and [Array#reverse](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse)  but not `Enumerable#reverse`. I therefore assume you want to create `my_map` as an instance method of the `Array` class, but you should specify that in your question. If you examine the doc for `Array#map` you'll see that the method returns one thing if it has a block and another--an enumerator--if it doesn't....

Comment: Returning an enumerator is important, in part because that's what allows chaining. For example, in `[1,2,3].map.with_index { |n,i| n+i } #=> [1, 3, 5]` `map` returns an enumerator. So if you want to mimic the behaviour of `Array#map` you need to deal with both cases.

Answer (score 4):

Are you asking how you put a method into a module? That's trivial:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_map(&block)
    mod_input = []
    x = -1
    while x < length - 1
      x = x + 1
      if block == nil
        return self
        break
      end
      mod_input.push(block.call(self[x]))
    end
    return mod_input
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].my_map(&2.method(:*))
# => [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Or are you asking how to make your method an `Enumerable` method? That's more involved: your method currently uses many methods that are not part of the [`Enumerable` API](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html). So, even *if* you make it a member of the `Enumerable` module, it won't be an `Enumerable` method. `Enumerable` methods can only use `each` or other `Enumerable` methods. You use `length` and `[]` both of which are not part of the `Enumerable` interface, for example, [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) doesn't respond to `[]`.

This would be a possible implementation, using the [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method:

```
module Enumerable
  def my_map
    return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
    inject([]) {|res, el| res << yield(el) }
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].my_map(&2.method(:*))
# => [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

A less elegant implementation using `each`

```
module Enumerable
  def my_map
    return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
    [].tap {|res| each {|el| res << yield(el) }}
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].my_map(&2.method(:*))
# => [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

---

Note that apart from being simply wrong, your code is very un-idiomatic. There is also dead code in there.

1. the `break` is dead code: the method `return`s in the line just before it, therefore the `break` will never be executed. You can just get rid of it.

   ```
   def my_map(&block)
     mod_input = []
     x = -1
     while x < length - 1
       x = x + 1
       if block == nil
         return self
       end
       mod_input.push(block.call(self[x]))
     end
     return mod_input
   end
   ```
2. Now that we have gotten rid of the `break`, we can convert the conditional into a guard-style statement modifier conditional.

   ```
   def my_map(&block)
     mod_input = []
     x = -1
     while x < length - 1
       x = x + 1
       return self if block == nil
       mod_input.push(block.call(self[x]))
     end
     return mod_input
   end
   ```
3. It also doesn't make sense that it is in the middle of the loop. It should be at the beginning of the method.

   ```
   def my_map(&block)
     return self if block == nil
     mod_input = []
     x = -1
     while x < length - 1
       x = x + 1
       mod_input.push(block.call(self[x]))
     end
     return mod_input
   end
   ```
4. Instead of comparing an object against nil, you should just ask it whether it is `nil?`: `block.nil?`

   ```
   def my_map(&block)
     return self if block.nil?
     mod_input = []
     x = -1
     while x < length - 1
       x = x + 1
       mod_input.push(block.call(self[x]))
     end
     return mod_input
   end
   ```
5. Ruby is an expression-oriented language, the value of the last expression that is evaluated in a method body is the return value of that method body, there is no need for an explicit `return`.

   ```
   def my_map(&block)
     return self if block.nil?
     mod_input = []
     x = -1
     while x < length - 1
       x = x + 1
       mod_input.push(block.call(self[x]))
     end
     mod_input
   end
   ```
6. `x = x + 1` is more idiomatically written `x += 1`.

   ```
   def my_map(&block)
     return self if block.nil?
     mod_input = []
     x = -1
     while x < length - 1
       x += 1
       mod_input.push(block.call(self[x]))
     end
     mod_input
   end
   ```
7. Instead of [`Array#push`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-push) with a single argument it is more idiomatic to use [`Array#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C).

   ```
   def my_map(&block)
     return self if block.nil?
     mod_input = []
     x = -1
     while x < length - 1
       x += 1
       mod_input << block.call(self[x])
     end
     mod_input
   end
   ```
8. Instead of [`Proc#call`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Proc.html#method-i-call), you can use the `.()` syntactic sugar.

   ```
   def my_map(&block)
     return self if block.nil?
     mod_input = []
     x = -1
     while x < length - 1
       x += 1
       mod_input << block.(self[x])
     end
     mod_input
   end
   ```
9. If you don't want to store, pass on or otherwise manipulate the block as an object, there is no need to capture it as a `Proc`. Just use `block_given?` and `yield` instead.

   ```
   def my_map
     return self unless block_given?
     mod_input = []
     x = -1
     while x < length - 1
       x += 1
       mod_input << yield(self[x])
     end
     mod_input
   end
   ```
10. This one is opinionated. You could move incrementing the counter into the condition.

    ```
    def my_map
      return self unless block_given?
      mod_input = []
      x = -1
      while (x += 1) < length
        mod_input << yield(self[x])
      end
      mod_input
    end
    ```
11. And then use the statement modifier form.

    ```
    def my_map
      return self unless block_given?
      mod_input = []
      x = -1
      mod_input << yield(self[x]) while (x += 1) < length
      mod_input
    end
    ```
12. Also, your variable names could use some improvements. For example, what does `mod_input` even mean? All I can see is that it is what you *output*, so why does it even have "input" in its name? And what is `x`?

    ```
    def my_map
      return self unless block_given?
      result = []
      index = -1
      result << yield(self[index]) while (index += 1) < length
      result
    end
    ```
13. This whole sequence of initializing a variable, then mutating the object assigned to that variable and lastly returning the object can be simplified by using the [*K Combinator*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus), which is available in Ruby as [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap).

    ```
    def my_map
      return self unless block_given?
      [].tap {|result| 
        index = -1
        result << yield(self[index]) while (index += 1) < length
      }
    end
    ```
14. The entire `while` loop is useless. It's just re-implementing [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-each), which is a) unnecessary because `Array#each` already exists, and b) means that your `my_map` method will only work with `Array`s but not other `Enumerable`s (for example `Set` or [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html)). So, let's just use `each` instead.

    ```
    def my_map
      return self unless block_given?
      [].tap {|result| 
        each {|element|
          result << yield(element)
        }
      }
    end
    ```

    Now it starts to look like Ruby code! What you had before was more like BASIC written in Ruby syntax.
15. This pattern of first creating a result object, then modifying that result object based on each element of a collection and in the end returning the result is very common, and it even has a fancy mathematical name: [*Catamorphism*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism), although in the programming world, we usually call it [`fold` or `reduce`](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)). In Ruby, it is called `Enumerable#inject`.

    ```
    def my_map
      return self unless block_given?
      inject([]) {|result, element|
        result << yield(element)
      }
    end
    ```
16. That `return self` is strange. `map` is supposed to return a *new* object! You don't return a *new* object, you return the *same* object. Let's fix that.

    ```
    def my_map
      return dup unless block_given?
      inject([]) {|result, element|
        result << yield(element)
      }
    end
    ```
17. And actually, `map` is also supposed to return an `Array`, but you return whatever it is that you called `map` on.

    ```
    def my_map
      return to_a unless block_given?
      inject([]) {|result, element|
        result << yield(element)
      }
    end
    ```
18. But *really*, if you look at the documentation of [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), you will find that it returns an `Enumerator` and not an `Array` when called without a block.

    ```
    def my_map
      return enum_for(:my_map) unless block_given?
      inject([]) {|result, element|
        result << yield(element)
      }
    end
    ```
19. And lastly, we can get rid of the hardcoded method name using the [`Kernel#__method__`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__) method.

    ```
    def my_map
      return enum_for(__method__) unless block_given?
      inject([]) {|result, element|
        result << yield(element)
      }
    end
    ```

Now, that looks a lot better!

Answer (score 3):

```
class Array
  def my_map(&block)
    # your code, replacing `input` with `self`
  end
end
```

The code itself is not really idiomatic Ruby - `while` is very rarely used for iteration over collections, and if you don't need to pass a block somewhere else, it is generally cleaner to use `block_given?` instead of `block.nil?` (let alone `block == nil`), and `yield input[x]` instead of `block.call(input[x])`.